# Geo location clustering

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, mahout

Problem:
Need to identify the home location of the IMEI no (User's home location).

I have a set of lat and long,imei and time it was recorded;

Note:

```
1.Recorded IMEI locations are not periodic.
2.Recorded IMEI locations doesn't has any pattern
3.Lat long locations are may not be recorded on every day.
```

So what I planned is,using a clustering algorithm.

If we cluster the lat and long locations means we can get set of cluster.In which I will concentrate two cluster.Cluster in which most of the latlong recorded on day time and cluster in which most of the latlong points recorded on night time.Then if cluster that has most of the latlong recorded at night times, will be considered as home location.

what I expect is which clustering algorithm is best suitable for this clustering job and how to use algorithm in java....?

Any one can suggest on it...?

Comment: Clustering algorithm: 1. Convert (latitude, longitude) to normalized (x,y,z), 2. Average all the (x,y,z), 3. Convert back to (latitude, longitude)

Comment: I did a similar thing and I used DBSCAN (with haversine distance) for that matter. It was pretty reliable once you find a good set of parameters (I tuned them with a GA algorithm later on).

Comment: Consider http://spark.apache.org/mllib/, especially for k-means

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a lot of work on this idea for animals - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_range, which lists various measures of geographical clustering. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_median#Spatial_median.

Your clustering method depends a lot on what the data look like - you could plot the locations associated with a given user on an X-Y graph or a map to see what sort of clusters to expect - in fact do this for several users.

My guess is that for most users there is one tight cluster which is their home and a very scattered cloud of stays away from home on work and holiday. In this case I would look to find the point such that the sum of the X% smallest distances to this point was as small as possible where X is maybe 80-90. You could do this with a modification of the usual k-means code, where you repeatedly alternate between finding the best fit point for a chosen X% of observations and choosing the X% of observations which are closest to the point you have just chosen.

K-means needs a decent starting point - in fact try several. Ideally you want a starting point which is not contaminated by any of the points in the outer cloud. If you generate a starting point by dividing your data up into 11 sections and taking the spatial median of each section this gives you 11 starting points, and if there are only 10 contaminated points in the cloud, at least one of the these starting points is derived from a collection of points which is completely uncontaminated.

I would expect to find a number of users who have two or more tight clusters rather than one, as well as an outer cloud. Some of these users will feel that revealing secondary clusters is a serious privacy violation.